# Onpress with conditional will not call a function

Tags: react-native

I have some problem with `onPress` button function,
if I create button and calling function directly it work well,
but if I'm using conditional it will not call the function.

I already create 2 button below to simulate, button with title "submit normal" can call function and pass the property successfully, button with title "submit conditional" will not calling `this.makeRemoteRequest.bind(this);` but if you put alert it will react normally, nothing happen if calling a function.

```
    <Input
      containerStyle={{ width: '90%' }}
      placeholder="Predefined User ID"
      label="User ID"
      labelStyle={{ marginTop: 16 }}
      editable={false}
      value={this.state.userid}
      onChangeText={input_user_id => this.setState({ input_user_id })}
    />

    <Input
      containerStyle={{ width: '90%' }}
      placeholder="Please fill services request notes here"
      label="Reason"
      labelStyle={{ marginTop: 16 }}
      onChangeText={input_services_detail => this.setState({ input_services_detail })}
    />

    <Button
        title='Submit Conditional'
        onPress={() => {
          if (this.state.input_services_detail != null)
          {
            this.makeRemoteRequest.bind(this);
          }
          else
          {
            Alert.alert('Please fill the service detail first');
          }
        }}><Text style={styles.buttonText}>Submit Aset</Text>
    </Button>

    <Button
        title='Submit Normal'
        onPress={this.makeRemoteRequest.bind(this)}><Text style={styles.buttonText}>Submit Aset</Text>
    </Button>

  </View>
```

Expecting to call a function using conditional. Appreciate if somebody can brief me on this. Thanks before.

Comment: may we have some feedback on the answers ?

Comment: hi adesuriah, your answer also help me to solve the conditional function, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say this is kind of a bad practice to achieve this behaviour.

A better way to write it would be like this -

```
<Button
    title='Submit Conditional'
    onPress={this.onPressSubmitButton.bind(this)}>
    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Submit Aset</Text>
</Button>
```

Changed the name of the onPress function to onPressSubmitButton

And the onPressSubmitButton function -

```
onPressSubmitButton() {
   if (this.state.input_services_detail === null) {
       return Alert.alert('Please fill the service detail first')
   }

   this.makeRemoteRequest()
}
```

I think it more clear to read and understand.

Also you can write the function signature like this  -

```
onPressSubmitButton = () => {
   ...
}
```

which make it bound already, this way you can call it like this -

```
<Button
    title='Submit Conditional'
    onPress={this.onPressSubmitButton}>
    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Submit Aset</Text>
</Button>
```

Comment: Hi nati, thanks for the brief explanation, so i follow the proper way to make conditional function based on your suggestion and it works! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling `this.makeRemoteRequest` in your condition, you're just binding it. Change your conditional `onPress` prop like this :

```
onPress={this.state.input_services_detail != null ? this.makeRemoteRequest.bind(this) : () => Alert.alert('Please fill the service detail first')}
```

And you don't need the `!= null` :

```
onPress={this.state.input_services_detail ? this.makeRemoteRequest.bind(this) : () => Alert.alert('Please fill the service detail first')}
```

Comment: Revision 3 was plagiarised (but function name was changed) from https://stackoverflow.com/a/56578839, which was posted before revision 3 (compare both posts' revision timestamps). Rolling back to revision 2.